# present UIViewController programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, segue

When I click on the newPostButton, I want to segue programmatically to the NewPostVC (which is that view on the right side).
However, the view does not show up on the simulator, as you can see, it's completely black.
What is the issue, why isn't the view showing up?
And how to fix that?
Thank you guys

[image: FeedVC.swift]
[image: Storyboard]
[image: Simulator]

Comment: did it presenting work ? only color is issue ???

Comment: No it did not work, the content of NewPostVC is not appearing at all.

Comment: Maybe i got it . you are trying to present with navigation-controller or presnt in presenting view controller ?? your code is yo are trying to push viewController .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying present view controller on your Navigation stack  so you need to do two thing set storyborad ID and set push viewController here is code :

Set 1:

set Storyboard ID : `NewPostVC` to your NewPostVC Storyborad

Step 2:

```
 @IBAction func newPostClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let storyborad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if let vc = storyborad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewPostVC") as? NewPostVC {
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }

    }
```